# how to share view(as image) through intent without saving

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap

i have a linear layout and i need to share this view through intent without saving,and i searched this but most answers propose solution witch first saves image then read image and share,but i don't want to save before sharing, this is my linear layout code:

```
   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/view_wanted"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="8"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:background="@drawable/bounty_frame">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/img_main"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:background="@drawable/framenew"
             android:paddingBottom="3dp"
             android:paddingLeft="3dp"
             android:paddingRight="3dp"
             android:paddingTop="3dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/next"
              />
         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img_main"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img_main"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_main"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_main"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:id="@+id/img_bar"/>
         </RelativeLayout>   
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've you try to use the [memory cache](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) for you're image ?
With this, when fecthing you picture, you flush it on the cache, so when you need to display it on your other view, it's here.
This way, the data isn't save, bau you can still access it from an other view